# AngleSharp Script not running - why?

Tags: c#, .net, anglesharp

I have installed AngleSharp to a new Visual Studio project (2017 and 2015) console application. The parser.Parse appears to work (no exceptions), but I can't see any scripts running. I've tried with a simple console.log script and some more complex scripts. I don't observe any script errors either.

Why? What am I not doing right?

I'm hoping to use console output as a way to debug javascript the same way I'd read the console window in a browser's developer tools window. Please let me know if there's anything special I need to do to capture javascript errors with AngleSharp too.

Thank you.

```
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Parser.Html;

namespace TestAngelSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = Configuration.Default.WithJavaScript();
            var parser = new HtmlParser(config);
            var source = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body><textarea>Test</textarea>
<script>console.log('hi');</script>
</body></html>";
            var document = parser.Parse(source);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console logger is not included any more (this makes the lib also a PCL with the same profile as the core lib).

So you could simply change your configuration to the following:

```
var config = Configuration.Default.
    WithConsoleLogger(ctx => new Logger()).
    WithJavaScript();
```

where the Logger is defined like

```
class Logger : IConsoleLogger
{
    public void Log(Object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!